# air/as3 : is there a way yto simulate TouchEvents?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5, flex4.6

Is there a way to simulate TouchEvent on AIR ?

I am developping a mobile game: TOUCHEvents work fine when I run the game on mobile.

I would like to test/debug on AIR : is there a way to test it on AIR ?

Regards

Comment: How are you deploying your game to "Mobile" if not using AIR?  Can you share some code?  Don't mouse click's simulate touch events?

Comment: I do use AIR.
I use flex: so I can run in on DESKTOP (Touchevents do not work) or on mobile (throush USB): Touchevents do work

Comment: Are you running it in an emulator?  Or are you actually deploying your application to the desktop?  What touch events are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach, you can add others touch events support by listening MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, etc :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;

    public class TestTouchEvent extends Sprite
    {
        public function TestTouchEvent()
        {
            stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick );
            stage.addEventListener( TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, onTap );
        }

        protected function onClick( event : MouseEvent ):void
        {
            event.target.dispatchEvent( new TouchEvent( TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP ) );
        }

        protected function onTap( event : TouchEvent ):void
        {
            trace("Tap event stuff");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could addEventListener for both Touch and Mouse and point them to same function.

```
this.addEventListener("touchBegin", onSomethingDown, false, 0 true);
this.addEventListener("mouseDown", onSomethingDown, false, 0 true);


function onSomethingDown(evt:Event):void
{
    var pointDown:Point;

    if (evt.type == "mouseDown") {
        pointDown.x = MouseEvent(evt).stageX;
        pointDown.y = MouseEvent(evt).stageY;
    } else if (evt.type == "touchBegin") {
        pointDown.x = TouchEvent(evt).stageX;
        pointDown.y = TouchEvent(evt).stageY;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is a poor idea. Event listeners are not a light process. Doubling the amount of listeners required for tasks, especially on mobile, could actually lead to a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `MouseEvent` instead of `TouchEvent`. There is no real way to simulate a touch event using the AIR simulator (though you could use the official Android and iOS simulators to do so) other than doubling event listeners, as suggested already, which you want to avoid (it is best practice to eliminate as many event listeners as possible, especially on mobile).

From my experience, `TouchEvent` offers little-to-no benefit over `MouseEvent`. As far as I have been able to tell, they may be a little more precise but I have no evidence to back that up. It also support proximity events from things like a stylus. For the large majority of apps, though, there is no benefit.

`MouseEvent` will work on *all* platforms, including mobile (touches on a mobile device also fire off `MouseEvent`s). And because `TouchEvent` maps out pretty much identically to `MouseEvent` (i.e. `TOUCH_TAP` to `CLICK`, `TOUCH_BEGIN` to `MOUSE_DOWN`). I currently have 8 AIR apps in the Play Store and 10 in the iTunes Store and not a single one uses `TouchEvent`, though some do utilize multitouch gestures.